# Frobenius norm of Hadamard product

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

I have an $(n\times n)$ real matrix obtained through the Hadamard product, $H=A\circ B$, of two real $(n\times n)$ symmetric matrices $A,B$. All elements of $A$ are positive, while diagonal elements of $B$ are zero and the rest are non-negative.

My question is if there is any way I can relate (possibly through some inequalities) the Frobenius norm of $H$ to the ones of $A, B$. The Frobenius norm of a real $(n\times n)$ matrix $M$ is defined as
$$
\| M \|_F = \sqrt{Tr\left(M^T M\right)} =\sqrt{\sum_{i,j=1}^n M_{i,j}^2} \,.
$$

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Cauchy Schwarz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $\|A\circ B\|_F\leq\operatorname{tr}(AB^T)\le\|A\|_F\|B\|_F$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I do not see how you get the first inequality. Can you pls explain?

Comment: @AG1123 Try to write down the squares of both sides in terms of the elements of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Yep, I see it now. Thanks!