# Is it correct for derivatives of matrix completion problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, matrix-calculus, matrix-completion

I am doing a matrix completion problem. Here is my object function:

$$\min_{U\ge0,V\ge0} \frac{\lambda}{2} \Vert \Omega \circ (UV^T - Y) \Vert_F^2 + \frac{1}{2} \Vert U \Vert_F^2 + \frac{1}{2} \Vert V \Vert_F^2$$

I read the post in [Derivative of Frobenius norm of Hadamard Product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2708167/derivative-of-frobenius-norm-of-hadamard-product), and I am just confused about the derivative of the first term. I try to derivate the gradient of the first term, here is my derivation:

Let $J(U, V) = \Vert M \Vert_F^2 = \Vert \Omega \circ (UV^T - Y) \Vert_F^2$, then

$$\begin{aligned}
dJ &= 2M : dM \\
&= 2M : \Omega \circ d(UV^T - Y) \\
&= 2 \Omega \circ M : d(UV^T-Y) \\ 
&= 2 \Omega \circ M : (U dV^T + dU V^T) \\
&= 2 (\Omega \circ M)^T U : dV + 2 (\Omega \circ M) V : dU
\end{aligned}$$

Let $dV = 0$, then we get

$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial U} = 2 (\Omega \circ M) V$$

Similarly for $V$:

$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial V} = 2 (\Omega \circ M)^T U$$

However, I am confused that $\Omega \circ M = \Omega \circ (\Omega \circ (UV^T - Y)) = \Omega^{\circ 2} \circ (UV^T - Y)$, i.e. I need to element-wise mutiply $\Omega$ twice! Is it correct?

---

Besides, is it correct to apply "alternating least square" and "multiplicative update rules" here to optimize the cost function? Thank you!

Comment: The gradients look correct. Since all of the elements of $\Omega$ are either zero or one, $\Omega\circ\Omega=\Omega$, so you only need to multiply once.

Comment: @greg OK. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Looks correct. You can also use the specialized computer algebra engine matrixcalculus.org to check matrix derivatives.